# How to hit/consume post and get api in React Native with Ignite Bowser 2 Boilerplate. (Mobx state stree, type script)

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, redux, mobx-state-tree

I am new to React Native, please provide some Github link or your own code for reference. Consider me as a beginner in RN.

I found very less open support for RN, Mobx State tree, Ignite and all, so not just post and get API reference, if you find anything helpful related to these above-mentioned topics, Feel free to share.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Mobx State Tree, With Ignite Bowler you would have api.ts file where you can specify API calls.

```
 async getUser(userToken: string): Promise<Types.GetUserResult> {
// make the api call

const response: ApiResponse<any> = await this.apisauce.post(`api/v1/sales/login?authCode=${userToken}`)

if (!response.ok) {
  const problem = getGeneralApiProblem(response)
  if (problem) return problem
}


// transform the data into the format we are expecting
try {
  try {
    const rawUser = response.data
    console.log('rawUser'+ rawUser)
    const user: UserSnapshot = convertRawUserToUserStore(rawUser)
    return { kind: "ok", user }
    console.log({ user })
  } catch (e) {
    __DEV__ && console.tron.log(e.message)
    return { kind: "bad-data" }
  }
} catch {
  return { kind: "bad-data" }
}
}
```

Consider, we will be getting user data from this API call,
you can notice that there is UserSnapshot which belongs to User Model, Snapshot will save the data automatically, you don't need Aysnc storage to save or retrieve data.